# Не работает CSS файл с динамическими страницами go gorilla/mux

Tags: css, golang

Всех приветствую

Пишу бек на **go** и обрабатываю динамические файлы сайта с помощью **gorilla/mux**.

```
rtr := mux.NewRouter()
rtr.HandleFunc("/post/{id:[0-9]+}", show_post).Methods("GET")
http.Handle("/", rtr)
```

Подключаю статические **CSS** файлы так:

```
rtr.PathPrefix("/static/").
  Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/",
    http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))))
```

**CSS** на всех страницах работает, кроме динамических и никак не могу это исправить.
Если посмотреть **CSS** файл в исходном коде страницы, то выдает ошибку **404**.

Бьюсь уже несколько дней и никак не могу решить данную проблему.

Comment: Покажите, как вы генерируете ссылку на `css` - там должен быть абсолютный путь. Например, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css"/>` - такой путь будет правильно распознаваться в любом сгенерированном файле.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Проблема была решена благодаря вашей меткой подсказке. Я упустил `/` перед указанием пути, то есть писал `href="static/style.css"/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В проекте `golang` подключаем `CSS` так:
`rtr.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))))`

В HTML шаблоне подключаем `CSS` так:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css"/>`

В таком случае `CSS` будет работать везде, в том числе в динамических страницах `gorilla/mux`.